# IndexError: list index out of range - a pesar de que el índice existe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

class Contacto:
    def __init__(self, nombre, telefono, correo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.correo = correo

class Agenda:
    def modificar_nombre(self, nombre):
        print("Hola")
    def modificar_telefono(self):
        pass
    def modificar_correo(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self._contactos = []

    def add(self,nombre,telefono,correo):
        contacto = Contacto(nombre,telefono,correo)
        self._contactos.append(contacto)
        self._save()

    def show_all(self):
        for contacto in self._contactos:
            self._imprimir_contacto(contacto)

    def _imprimir_contacto(self, contacto):
            print(" +-----------------------------------------+")
            print("     Nombre: {}".format(contacto.nombre))
            print("     Telefono: {}".format(contacto.telefono))
            print("     Correo: {}".format(contacto.correo))
            print(" +-----------------------------------------+")

    def eliminar(self, nombre):
        for idx, contacto in enumerate(self._contactos):
            if contacto.nombre.lower() == nombre.lower():
                del self._contactos[idx]
                self._save()
                break

    def buscar(self, nombre):
        for contacto in self._contactos:
            if contacto.nombre.lower() == nombre.lower():
                self._imprimir_contacto(contacto)
                break
        else:
            self._no_encontrado()
    def _save(self):
        with open("contactos.csv", "w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(("Nombre", "Telefono", "Correo"))
            for contacto in self._contactos:
                writer.writerow((contacto.nombre,contacto.telefono,contacto.correo))

    def _no_encontrado(self):
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        print("!No se ha encontrado el contacto :(   !")
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

    def actualizar_contacto(self, nombre):
        for contacto in self._contactos:
            if contacto.nombre.lower() == nombre.lower():
                comando2 = str(input(
                """     ¿Que deseas modificar de {}?
        +----------------------+
        |   [n]ombre       |
        |   [t]elefono     |
        |   [c]orreo       |
        +----------------------+
                """.format(nombre)))

            if comando2 == "n":
                modificar_nombre(contacto.nombre)
            elif comando2 == "t":
                modificar_telefono()
            elif comando2 == "c":
                modificar_correo()
            else:
                break

def run():
    agenda = Agenda()

    with open("contactos.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            if idx == 0:
                continue
            agenda.add(row[0], row[1], row[2])

    while True:
        print("      +-------------------------------+")
        print("      |BIENVENIDO A TU AGENDA PERSONAL|")
        print("      +-------------------------------+")

        comando = str(input(
        """     ¿Que deseas hacer?
    +---------------------------------+
    |   [a]gregar contacto        |
    |   [e]liminar contacto       |
    |   [m]odificar contacto      |
    |   [v]er contactos           |
    |   [b]uscar contacto         |
    |   [s]alir                   |
    +---------------------------------+
        """))

        if comando == "a":
            nombre = str(input("Ingrese el nombre de su nuevo contacto: "))
            telefono = int(input("Ingresa el numero de su nuevo contacto: "))
            correo = str(input("Ingresa el correo electronico de su nuevo contacto: "))
            agenda.add(nombre, telefono, correo)
        elif comando == "e":
            nombre = str(input("Escribe el nombre del contacto a eliminar: "))
            agenda.eliminar(nombre)
        elif comando == "m":
            nombre = str(input("Escribe el nombre del contacto a modificar: "))
            agenda.actualizar_contacto(nombre)
        elif comando == "v":
            agenda.show_all()
        elif comando == "b":
            nombre = str(input("Ingresa el nombre del contacto a buscar: "))
            agenda.buscar(nombre)
        elif comando == "s":
            break
        else:
            print("Comando erroneo")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Me da un error en la siguiente parte del código:

```
def run():
    agenda = Agenda()

    with open("contactos.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            if idx == 0:
                continue
            agenda.add(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

Me marca un `list index out of range` pero el índice si existe.

Comment: Hola Fernando, estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor, edita la pregunta y tradúcela al español. También, copia el código relevante a la pregunta en sí.

Comment: Comprueba si cada una de las filas leídas contiene tres elementos, porque la excepción que te salta es porque al intentar acceder a `row` no existe ningún elemento para uno de los tres índices.

Comment: Es posible que se trate de una línea en blanco en el .csv, quizás la última línea del archivo. Yo pondria un `if len(row)<3: continue` para saltarme las líneas que no tengan al menos 3 campos.

Comment: ¿Estás realmente que existen tres campos en cada registro? Muestra datos de depuración con `print("Número de elementos en la línea " + idx + ": " + len(row) + "\n")` dentro del bucle `for idx, row in enumerate(reader):`.

Answer (score 1):

Es difícil saber a ciencia cierta lo que está pasando sin ver el error completo y sin saber sobre qué datos estás trabajando (es decir, el contenido de tu archivo `contactos.csv`). Sin embargo, puedo darte algunos consejos que tal vez te sirvan para resolver tu problema.

1. Si quieres obviar la primera línea de tu archivo CSV (la cabecera), no es necesario un contador. Basta con llamar al método `reader.next()` antes de comenzar la iteración:

   ```
   reader.next()
   ```
2. Si en algún momento quieres conocer la línea actual del archivo CSV que está siendo procesada puedes usar el atributo `reader.line_num`.

   ```
   for row in reader:
       print(reader.line_num, row)
   ```

   Daría como resultado:

   ```
   1 ['Nombre', 'Edad']
   2 ['Cesar', '32']
   3 ['Fiorella', '26']
   4 ['Ignacio', '1']
   ...
   ```
3. Si estás seguro de que la cantidad de columnas por cada línea es una constante entonces una buena forma de evadir los errores del tipo `IndexError` es evitando evaluar aquellas filas cuya cantidad de columnas sean menor a esa cantidad:

   ```
   total_columnas = 3
   for row in reader:
       if len(row) < total_columnas:
           continue
   ```

   Lo más razonable sería considerar la cantidad de columnas con respecto a la cabecera del archivo, por lo tanto, algo como esto podría también ser válido:

   ```
      total_columnas = len(reader.next())
   ```

En resumen, tu código para procesar el archivo CSV podría ser actualizado para verse algo así:

```
def run():
    agenda = Agenda()

    with open("contactos.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        # Para obtener la cantidad total de columnas y
        # de paso deshacerte de la cabecera
        total_columnas = len(reader.next())
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) < total_columnas:
                continue
            agenda.add(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```